# Publishing from CI build to Nuget only if changes in project

Tags: git, tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Background: C# .NET in TFS2015 and VC source control. CI using TFSBuilds. Internal Proget server, already publishing Nuget packages from other TFSBuilds.

I am looking to move a collection of framework projects into their own Git repo. Below is a sample of it's structure for reference.

```
Framework.sln
  IO.proj
  Logging.proj
  Other.proj
```

My confusion comes from how to design the CI build(s?) so that only those projects that have been changed will get new packages published. Currently I have a CI build that builds the Framework.sln, and then packages and publishes all outputs from that to Proget, incrementing the package version using BuildNumber.

Obviously this is an issue as a single change to Logging.proj will kick off the CI build and I end up with a new version of each package published even though there is only a change to 1. Before we switched to TFSBuild we had MSBuild running bitdiffer to compare differences and increment version numbers automatically.

What I'm wondering is do I have to have a CI build per project, can TFS handle this scenario using something else, or am I missing something very obvious.

Note: I have left the branching strategy out of all this as I don't think it matters, whatever way branches are managed this issue will still occur, but if I'm wrong then let me know.

Comment: If this is better suited to one of the other areas in Stack Exchange then please feel free to move it. Seemed a bit too vague/general for an SO question, but couldn't figure out where else it would go.

Comment: Accepting first answer just to close out question. I think that what I'm asking isn't possible given the requirements and constraints. Would close/delete question but don't know how, so if an admin wants to come along and do that feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the VSTS/TFS build to only occur when changes happen in a specific path or folder, so in your case you may end up with 3 builds building each individual project

Answer (score 1):

It's suggested to upgrade your TFS 2015 to TFS 2017.1 and higher version. In new versions of TFS, you can set Path filters in CI trigger:

[image]

Comment: Is this the equivalent of CI trigger filters in TFS2015 with TFVC?

Comment: Yes, they both are path filter.

Comment: Unfortunately not for my scenario Cece, as this would require me to have separate CI builds triggering for each project, which is something I was hoping to avoid (mentioned in the initial question but I could have been clearer about it)